# Fetch images from specific patch php

Tags: php

How to get all images from specific directory.Like `$Dir = 'images/marriage/';`

**Result**

```
<img src="img1.png">
<img src="img2.png">
<img src="img3.png">
<img src="img4.png">
<img src="img5.png">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.  Put the file containing the code in the directory that contains the "images" directory

```
<?php

$dir = "images/marriage/";

$files = scandir($dir);

Foreach($files as $filename){
   echo "<img src='".$dir."$filename'><br/>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have attempted something, but:

```
foreach(glob($Dir.'*.*') as $name) {
    //echo your img using $name
}
```

or `*.jpg` or whatever, or lookup `glob()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/scandir:

```
foreach (scandir($Dir) as $img) {
    if ($img[0] != '.') print '<img src="' . $img . '">';
}
```